# Constructing a random sampler from a random coin (algorithm)

Tags: probability, algorithms

This is a problem from Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et. al. Assume that we can do coin-flips. The problem is to come up with an algorithm that can uniformly sample from the interval $[1,n]$.

The following approach immediately came to my mind. If $n$ is even, then we may recursively assume that we can do this for the intervals $[1,n/2]$ and $[n/2+1,n]$, so we do the following:

1. Flip a coin to choose one of the subintervals
2. Pick uniformly a number from the chosen subinterval.

The trickier case seems to be when $n$ is odd. In this case, I can reduce to the even case by sampling uniformly from the interval $[1,n+1]$ (which I can do using the previous method) and then repeat this until I receive a value, which is not $n+1$.

The problem with the approach in the odd case is that theoretically it can keep going on forever, though this would be highly improbable. I was wondering whether there is a way of doing this without relying on possible infinite behavior?

A sort of quick heuristic idea I had is that it's not possible, since when you write down the expected probabilities and if $n$ is some odd prime $p$, then in the expressions, I don't see how $p$ could appear in the denominator, so it would seem impossible to get $1/p$ out of this as the probability without some limit behavior.

Anyone have any insights on this?

Answer (score 1):

You must be williung to waste some coin tosses.
A simple approach is this:

> Find $k$ such that $2^k\ge n>2^{k-1}$. Then make $k$ coin tosses, the rsults of which can be interpreted as binary digits for a random number $X$ between $0$ and $2^k-1$, inclusive. If $X<n$ output $X+1$ (because we want $[1,n]$ instead of $[0,n-1]$). Otherwise, start again from the beginning.

The probability of success in each round is $\frac{n}{2^k}>\frac12$. Hence we will succeed eventually a.s., the expected number of rounds being less than $2$.

Another approach that is suitable for any finite distribution with possibly different probabilities $p_1,\ldots, p_n$ (with $p_1+\ldots+p_n=1$):
Let $s_0=0, s_1=p_1, s_2=p_1+p_2, \ldots, s_n=p_1+\ldots+p_n=1$.
Now repeately toss the coin, interpreting the results as binary digits $0$ and $1$. This produces a binary expansion $0.x_1x_2x_3\ldots$ of a number between $0$ and $1$. Almost surely, after finitely many tosses you will obtain a number such that for some $k$ the number is $\ge s_{k-1}$ and even if you would only otss $1$s from now on it can never become $>s_k$. In that case output $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two parts. First the algorithm, which will be based on [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). Second part, why does the algorithm stop.

The first one is the algorithm. Your case needs $\log_2(n) \in \mathbb{N}$. That part of the question is answered [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29204/how-to-simulate-a-die-given-a-fair-coin). The first answer is just like your algorithm. The second answer is a quicker version.

Now to the second part. This is the most interesting part. The algorithm does not have a deterministic stopping time *but* is a **finite** stopping time with probability 1 (as shown by the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)).

In the simplest case, it would be like how many times can you lose in a row at a fair coin toss. For $k$ throws that would be $1/2^k$.

Lets say $k=270$ tries. For a modern processor with a frequency of about $\sim 3$ GHz it would take about $2 \cdot 10^{-6}$ seconds to generate $270$ coin tosses.

$2^{-270} \approx 10^{-81}$. Take a hat and put all the atoms in the **Observable Universe** in it. Pick out a random atom and label it Alice. Put it back in the hat. The chance of picking it up again from the hat is about the same as losing 270 coin tosses in a row.